# How to update corresponding UI using Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

In my form there are two controls for the same function but the control type is different from one another, one is textbox and other is dropdownlist.

In my case if user selects an option from dropdown the textbox value updated dynamically but the problem arises when I type value in textbox, the dropdownlist not updated. If he typed single character it will work fine but it gives trouble where I typed code more than a character.

Js Fiddle here:

```
                   jsfiddle.net/rohit421991/c38hkdag/32/
```

I think I have used wrong event and I am using keyup event.
Please let me know what is the best way of doing this and how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I found a solution :) please bare in mind that I am also new to KO!

First things first... hooking up to the keyup bind feels like the wrong way to do this in KO, somthing like a subscribe makes more sense....

so here is my solution:

```
   jsfiddle.net/2kx9g6es/8/
```

I've changed a few minor things:

1. changed the data array to have lower case names
2. renamed text on the vm to code because code makes more sense + text is used as an element attr so      probably good pracitice not to use text.
3. ditched using events, now using subscribe
4. put the subscribe into jquery's on ready to avoid any weird errors

The code may be a wii bit confusing around the subscribe, but this was because I smashed face against keyboard until it worked... basically all it does is on one of them changing, looks at the other one to see if it's value is correct, if it isn't, update it. The extra code around it is to solve one subscribe triggering another which triggers the other (a loop of some sort)

There is probably a more elegant (and more reusable way, maybe via custom bindings!) to do this, but this should work.

If you feel like improving your code I would suggest looking maybe making a custom directive to solve the issue.. or maybe just re-structure my subscribes to be more logical.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Also.. why are you using KO 3.0?

Comment: ahh because thats the only official CDN

Comment: Thanks for reply and good suggestions. But I want to populate data on dropdown as user press any code in textbox, it is now showing data when I move focus from textbox.

Comment: Once again, you should choose options provided by the library over event listening... In knockout 3.2+ instead of binding the textbox to value, use textInput, but as the demo you are using is 3.0 simply replace the texbox binding with thefollowing: data-bind="value: code, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"

Comment: 3.0 fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2kx9g6es/9/ 3.2 fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2kx9g6es/10/ - The advantage (and why you should use textInput) is that it's more designed for mobile browser input as it works better with clipboards and autocorrect.. See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html for more info

Comment: Ok. It is working but it is giving some weird output in some case please you test it. So I replace it with jquery functions for the time being. http://jsfiddle.net/rohit421991/0sg669fq/1/